# Execute multiple command onto same terminal using bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sudo, dir

I am trying to run a **bash script** which contains few commands to execute. I want to open a terminal and **execute multiple commands** into it. I have written commands to set the directory path and want to make a folder there.

**Code :**

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/var/run/ 
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"sudo mkdir sphinxsearch; exec bash\""
```

Here, There are 2 problems :

1) Two separate terminal are opened that I don't want. I need only a **single terimal** where I will execute my commands.

2) **sudo mkdir sphinxsearch** folder is created at the **default path** from where I am executing my bash script. I need to create a folder inside **/var/run/**

Comment: Why don't you put the `--working-directory` option on the second command?

Comment: Because I want to make folder inside **/var/run**. I got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each invocation of `gnome-terminal` will open a separate terminals.

Try this:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/var/run/ -e "bash -c \"sudo mkdir sphinxsearch; exec bash\""
```

Here i am combining both options in a single invocation of `gnome-terminal`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/sphinxsearch;
```

will create the folder in `/var/run/`